# Mediapipe, assign the landmarks to the vertices?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, blender, mediapipe

[Here](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/tree/master/mediapipe/modules/face_geometry/data) is the face in fbx format that mediapipe uses for their face mesh model. It has 468 vertices.
[Here](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/modules/face_geometry/data/canonical_face_model_uv_visualization.png) is the visualisation of the indices.

[Here](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/face_mesh.html) is the description of mediapipes face mesh model. It outputs landmark positions.

How do I know which landmark belongs to which vertices?
For example in blender. When I import the fbx face, how can I get the same indices like the landmarks of the mediapipe face mesh model?

Comment: Your [mre] needs to be contained within your post; a StackOverflow question can't rely on external sites in order to be answered. See [ask] for why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like indices in the blender with fbx model are same as those provided from mediapipe face mesh solution. These indices are same as those in the mediapipe [canonical face model uv visualization](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/modules/face_geometry/data/canonical_face_model_uv_visualization.png). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67141844/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-face-mash-landmarks-in-mediapipe) provides example to get a landmark by its index.

Need to have `Developer Extras` enabled. In edit mode the option is shown under `Viewport Overlays > Developer > Indices` as shown below to get indices in blender. Alternate option to get indices can be [found here](https://github.com/quickgrid/CodeLab/blob/master/computer_vision/mediapipe_3d_face_mesh_indices_HELP.md).

I have shown an example below with left eye landmark indices as they appear in canonical face mesh uv visualization.

#### Indices Visualization

[image]

[image]

#### Code

Code based on, https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/face_mesh.html.

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles
mp_face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh

# For static images:

import glob
IMAGE_FILES = glob.glob('img.jpg')


drawing_spec = mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(thickness=1, circle_radius=1)
with mp_face_mesh.FaceMesh(
    static_image_mode=True,
    max_num_faces=1,
    refine_landmarks=True,
    min_detection_confidence=0.5) as face_mesh:
  for idx, file in enumerate(IMAGE_FILES):
    image = cv2.imread(file)
    # Convert the BGR image to RGB before processing.
    results = face_mesh.process(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

    # Print and draw face mesh landmarks on the image.
    if not results.multi_face_landmarks:
      continue
    annotated_image = image.copy()

    landmarks_list = [
        33, 7, 163, 144, 145, 153, 154, 155,
        133, 173, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 246
    ]

    for face_landmarks in results.multi_face_landmarks:
      #print('face_landmarks:', face_landmarks)

      print(len(face_landmarks.landmark))
    #   print(face_landmarks.landmark[7])

      for idx in landmarks_list:
        loc_x = int(face_landmarks.landmark[idx].x * image.shape[1])
        loc_y = int(face_landmarks.landmark[idx].y * image.shape[0])
        print(loc_x, loc_y)
        cv2.circle(annotated_image,(loc_x, loc_y), 2, (255,255,255), 2)

    cv2_imshow(annotated_image)
```

#### Output

[image]

##### Demo notebook

https://github.com/quickgrid/AI-Resources/blob/master/code-lab/computer_vision/Mediapipe_Python_Holistic_and_Face_Mesh.ipynb